# Magento 2 - Plugin - afterGetPrice() - not working in backend

Tags: magento2

I have a plugin running afterGetPrice(). This is working correctly in the frontend but does not work in the admin area.
I have placed my di.xml in the following locations:

```
<moduleDir>/etc/frontend/di.xml
<moduleDir>/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
```

The content of these di.xml files is:

**adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="sulman-product-model-admin" type="Sulman\Test\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="sulman-product-model-frontend" type="Sulman\Test\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

My Plugin code is:

```
<?php
namespace Sulman\Test\Plugin;

class ProductPlugin
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return 123.45;
    }
}
?>
```

It all looks OK but it's not changing the price in the admin.

Any ideas?

*(all cache etc cleaned, content deployed, etc etc)*

Answer (score 0):

Not all requests are in the frontend and adminhtml area. Try using a single file di.xml

```
<moduleDir>/etc/di.xml
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding the global di.xml didn't have any effect though.